# install tkinter on mac os and pyenv

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, virtualenv, pyenv

When I import tkinter, I get this error:

```
No module named '_tkinter'
```

I used both the installation here:
https://platform.activestate.com/oferlip/ActiveTcl-8.5/distributions

and also tried this command:

```
brew install tcl-tk
```

I saw in this github comment:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375#issuecomment-533182043

which states that I need to uninstall and then reinstall the pyenv (after installing tck-tk).

I have a lot of installation on my pyenv, is there a way to use tkinter without uninstalling my virtualenv ?

Answer (score 0):

I looked it up, and I am pretty sure Tkinter comes pre-installed with Python

Try:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    print("It works!")
```

Good luck!

Comment: I am getting the error:Traceback (most recent call last):

import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

It is possible that it is not preinstalled in pyenv

Comment: What version of Python do you have?

Comment: My Python version is 3.7.8

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Python and reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, 
And it works.
I tried to avoid that, in order to not reinstall all the packages I had

Answer (score 0):

brew install python-tk@3.9

[see this formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/python-tk@3.9#default)

Answer (score 0):

Using `tkinter` with `pyenv` can be tricky due to missing dependencies.

The following two steps should help you fix the ﻿`tkinter` and ﻿`pyenv` issue.

### Step 1: Installing Necessary System Packages

Using `tkinter` with `pyenv` can be tricky due to missing dependencies.

First, let's make sure we have installed the necessary system packages for `tkinter`.

On macOS, you can use Homebrew:

```bash
brew install tcl-tk
```

### Step 2: Linking the Correct Tcl/Tk Versions

Next, make sure you link the correct versions of Tcl/Tk when installing Python. `pyenv` builds Python in your environment, but if you don't have the required dependencies, like the Tk/Tcl libraries, it'll build Python without them.

If the Python version you want to use is already installed on your system, you'll need to uninstall it before proceeding. For example:

```bash
pyenv uninstall 3.11.3
```

When installing a new Python version with `pyenv`, use the following commands:

For macOS, after installing tcl-tk with brew:

```bash
brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib

env LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix sqlite3)/lib -L$(brew --prefix xz)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib" \
CPPFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(brew --prefix sqlite3)/include -I$(brew --prefix xz)/include -I$(brew --prefix zlib)/include -I$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/include" \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix readline)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix sqlite3)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix xz)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib/pkgconfig:$(brew --prefix tcl-tk)/lib/pkgconfig" \
pyenv install <version>
```

Replace `<version>` with the version of Python you want to install. After that, you should be able to import `tkinter` in your `pyenv` Python environment.

Note that I couldn't get ﻿`tkinter` to work with ﻿`pyenv` on Python ﻿`3.11.0`, but it worked perfectly on `﻿3.11.2`.